# How to make list by recursion?

Tags: clojure, lisp

In many cases I want to make list by recursion function an I can not find right way how to do it.

For example (Not usefull but shortest I can find) I want to take elements from list one by one and create new list that is same as first one.

```
(defn f [x] (list 
          (first x) 
          (if (not= (rest x) '())
          (f (rest x))
          '()       
)))

(f '(1 2 3))
```

I want to get

```
(1 2 3)
```

but I get

```
(1 (2 (3 ())))
```

I want to do not use flatten.
For example this imput

```
(f '([1 1] [2 2] [3 3]))
```

will be destroyed by flatten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `list` with `cons`:

```
(defn f [x] 
  (cons (first x) 
        (if (not= (rest x) '())
          (f (rest x))
          '())))
```

Operation `(list x y)` returns list of two elements: `(x y)`.  Operation `(cons x y)` returns list which head (i.e. first element) is `x` and tail (the rest of the list) is `y` where `y` should be list itself.

Comment: Shouldn't be there "y must be list" instead of "y should be list"? 
(cons 1 1)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Integer (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
(cons 1 [1])
(1 1)

Comment: @boucekv This depends on Lisp flavor.  In some flavors pair may consist of two non-null atoms.

Comment: This will have a problem if passed an empty list. It would be better to check for an empty list before taking first element: `(if (= x '()) '() (cons (first x) (f (rest x))))`.